# Polymer display content based on URL

Tags: polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

I'm trying to create a custom element for reuse. What I have is data consisting of three attributes that will be displayed on it's respective page, depending on the link you click.

I'm using the [Polymer Starter Kit](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit). Basically, I want to have a page of information that changes depending on what the URL is. I have a list of programs on a page with links to their respective pages. So far I have this:

In my index.html, I have a section that looks like this:

```
<section data-route="programs">
<paper-material elevation="1">
<h1>Programs</h1>
<a href$="{{baseUrl}}programs/firstprogram">Program 1</a></br>
<a href$="{{baseUrl}}programs/secondprogram">Program 2</a></br>
<a href$="{{baseUrl}}programs/thirdprogram">Program 3</a></br>
</paper-material>
</section>
```

Then I have a custom element, program-info, that looks like this

```
<dom-module id="program-info">
  <template>
    <h2 class="page-title">{{program.name}}</h2>
    <p>{{program.price}}</p>
    <p>{{program.description}}</p>
  </template>
  <script>
    (function() {
      'use strict';
      Polymer({
        is: 'program-info'
      });
    })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Based on the program that was clicked, I want to grab data and use it in my custom element (name, price, description).  I've thought about putting it in an array since there are only seven programs, but I don't know understand how to grab the right item in the array based on the URL.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Perhaps https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/carbon-route does what you want

Comment: I've looked over it, it doesn't seem to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are indeed using PSK, take a look at the section/page `user-info` in `app/index.html`. It displays information about a user based the name that was grabbed from the URL.

Of course you should also take a look at the routing configuration in `app/elements/routing.html` to figure out how the name is grabbed from the URL and set to the `params` variable.

Then you should add/modify your `programs` route to suit your needs.

**Edit:**

You can see a similar approach in this sample app : The [data is fetch](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/zuperkulblog-progressive/blob/master/app/static/scripts/app.js#L118) when the [route changes](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/zuperkulblog-progressive/blob/master/app/static/scripts/app.js#L116) and is then [set to an `article` property](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/zuperkulblog-progressive/blob/master/app/static/scripts/app.js#L123) in the scope of the [`blog-app` element](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/zuperkulblog-progressive/blob/master/app/static/elements/blog-app.html). In this element, said `article` property is itself bound to the [similarly named property of the "page element" `article-detail`](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/zuperkulblog-progressive/blob/master/app/static/elements/blog-app.html#L237) that is in charge of displaying the article's content that was previously fetched over the network.

Comment: Correct, that's easy enough, but not entirely what I'm looking for.  The user-info page only displays the name of the user based on the URL.  I need to go beyond that, and display additional data based on the URL.  Take the user-info for example, let's say I want to display the users age and occupation as well.  I'll store that information in a json file or an array, but ultimately need to pull that information based on the user. All PSK does is uses the name from the URL, nothing else.

Comment: Did you extract each page to an element ? If so, you can simply observe changes to this `params` property, test if your page is indeed the selected one, and fetch the data you need from your array, or JSON using `iron-ajax`

Comment: I just found this, think it's what you're talking about @vincent guillou? http://polymerlabs.github.io/app-layout/templates/publishing/#/art/list

Comment: That is not exactly what I suggested (data fetching is handled directly when the route changes in this example in `app.js`) but this approach should be working fine as well.

Comment: What example in app.js?

Comment: An example of what you want to do : Fetch data from a parameter in the URL. I'll edit my answer to include that example: Check the source code of zuperkulblog: https://github.com/PolymerLabs/zuperkulblog-progressive/blob/master/app/static/scripts/app.js#L116

Comment: OK, same content in that example as the link I had. PSK is starting to implement carbon-route, which looks to handle this scenario after all, so I'll try that route (no pun intended)

Comment: Look at my updated answer for more details. Everything that you are asking for is there: Either your question does not expose the problem completely (in which case you should update your question), or something is still not clear for you (in which case I'm happy to help if you tell specifically what it is).

Comment: Oh sorry, yea wasn't very clear in my last comment. The example you provided is from zuperkulblog. It's the same "app" as the link I had, but using routing coded in the app.js file. The link I added uses the newer carbon-route in the blog-app.html file https://github.com/PolymerLabs/app-layout/blob/master/templates/publishing/src/blog-app.html and gets data a little bit differently, which I think is the way I want to go.